# Leading Zeros with Python 3.9 csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

3.9 Python Panda Cannot parse leading zeros.

With Python 3.8 it was fine:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(example.csv, , index_col = False)
```

**example.csv**

```
"TradeDate","Client Code","TradePrice","Maturity","ProductName","Exchange","FuturesCode","B/S","Quantity","TradeType","PutorCall","StrikePrice","Currency","COMMISSION","ExchangeFEE","NFAFEE","Brokerage","Exec comms","Total fees","OtherFee","GiveInFee","ExpiryDate","Notional Value","Notional Value + Fees","LastTradeDate","SettlementDate","BUSINESSDATE","OPT_EXERCISE_STYLE","DELIVERY_MONTH","TRADE_TYPE","DEAL_ID"
"20220210","52613676",0000004.07500000,"202202","09 FEB 22 IFD CSS2 IFD Fixed price For Gas daily Chica","39","CSS","S",00001,"Mandatory Settlement","",0000000.00000000,"USD",-00000000000000000000000000000.22,-00000000000000000000000000000.02,-00000000000000000000000000000.02,00000000000000000000000000000.00,00000000000000000000000000000.00,-00000000000000000000000000000.26,0000000000,0000000000,"20220208",00000000000000000000000010187.50,00000000000000000000000010187.24,"20220208","20220128","20220210","A","2022-02-09","Daily Futures",""
"20220210","52613676",0000004.07500000,"202202","09 FEB 22 IFD CSS2 IFD Fixed price For Gas daily Chica","39","CSS","S",00001,"Mandatory Settlement","",0000000.00000000,"USD",-00000000000000000000000000000.22,-00000000000000000000000000000.02,-00000000000000000000000000000.02,00000000000000000000000000000.00,00000000000000000000000000000.00,-00000000000000000000000000000.26,0000000000,0000000000,"20220208",00000000000000000000000010187.50,00000000000000000000000010187.24,"20220208","20220128","20220210","A","2022-02-09","Daily Futures",""
"20220210","52613676",0000004.07500000,"202202","09 FEB 22 IFD CSS2 IFD Fixed price For Gas daily Chica","39","CSS","S",00001,"Mandatory Settlement","",0000000.00000000,"USD",-00000000000000000000000000000.22,-00000000000000000000000000000.02,-00000000000000000000000000000.02,00000000000000000000000000000.00,00000000000000000000000000000.00,-00000000000000000000000000000.26,0000000000,0000000000,"20220208",00000000000000000000000010187.50,00000000000000000000000010187.24,"20220208","20220128","20220210","A","2022-02-09","Daily Futures",""
```

Comment: Please format your code as code.

Comment: I just tried with 3.9.7, see below. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected just the **Notional Value** field and saved it to a separate file, tmp.csv:

```
Notional Value
00000000000000000000000010187.50
00000000000000000000000010187.50
00000000000000000000000010187.50
```

Now I'm running Python **3.8.11**:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys

print(f'Python: {sys.version}')
print(f'Pandas: {pd.__version__}')

df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', index_col=False)
print(df)
```

```
Python: 3.8.11 (default, Aug 16 2021, 12:04:33) [Clang 12.0.0 ]
Pandas: 1.4.1
   Notional Value
0             0.0
1             0.0
2             0.0
```

Do you need all those leading zeros? Can you just clean your data?

```py
import csv

# Read in rows as is and convert to DF to verify truncation
old_rows = []
with open('too_many_zeroes.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        old_rows.append(row)

print('Original')
print(pd.DataFrame(old_rows))

# Fix old rows by removing *leading* zeroes
import re

new_rows = []
for row in old_rows:
    new_row = []
    for col in row:
        new_col = col

        # Find all leading zeroes with-or-without minus sign
        match = re.match(r'-?(0+)', col)
        if match:
            # "Slice-out zeroes" by taking everything before and after match
            new_col = new_col[0:match.start(1)] + new_col[match.end(1):]

        new_row.append(new_col)

    new_rows.append(new_row)

print('Cleaned')
print(pd.DataFrame(new_rows))
```

I get:

```
Original
                 0                 1                                  2                                  3   ...          8           9                                 10                                11
0  0000004.07500000  0000000.00000000  -00000000000000000000000000000.22  -00000000000000000000000000000.02  ...  0000000000  0000000000  00000000000000000000000010187.50  00000000000000000000000010187.24
1  0000004.07500000  0000000.00000000  -00000000000000000000000000000.22  -00000000000000000000000000000.02  ...  0000000000  0000000000  00000000000000000000000010187.50  00000000000000000000000010187.24
2  0000004.07500000  0000000.00000000  -00000000000000000000000000000.22  -00000000000000000000000000000.02  ...  0000000000  0000000000  00000000000000000000000010187.50  00000000000000000000000010187.24
```

and

```
Cleaned
           0          1     2     3     4    5    6     7  8  9         10        11
0  4.07500000  .00000000  -.22  -.02  -.02  .00  .00  -.26        10187.50  10187.24
1  4.07500000  .00000000  -.22  -.02  -.02  .00  .00  -.26        10187.50  10187.24
2  4.07500000  .00000000  -.22  -.02  -.02  .00  .00  -.26        10187.50  10187.24
```

Comment: I have 3.9.4. Look for Notional Value column. Trade price is parsed correctly, not the fields which has 00000000000000000000000000 so many zeros.

Comment: If this works for you may be I need to update to higher Python version from 3.9.4 to 3.9.7

Comment: I'm on 3.10, now, but yeah, it works.

Comment: You are getting notional valuse as 0 in you data above. Thats what the issue it. It has a value of 10187.50

Comment: Ah, now I see you. You really need to update your question: it's entirely unclear what your issue, and it's only through comments that the problem is emerging. It'd be more _helpful for you_ to be as clear and concise what your needs and issues are. And cut away the data isn't the issue... this problem-column is around the 25th out of 30 or so... highlight it... bring it to our attention. Cheers.

Comment: I just installed Python 3.8.11 and Pandas and I get same _truncating_ behavior.

Comment: I also propose just cleaning your data before converting to DF, please see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. The row approach works fine